# NetBeans 12.5 java.lang no se reconoce

Tags: java, netbeans

Tenia el jdk 1.8 y me pase al jdk 19 y comenzó mi dolor de cabeza, ya limpie la Cache de NetBeans, desinstale y reinstale NetBeans 12.5 para que automáticamente reconozca el jdk, las variables de entorno apuntan al jdk 19 pero el error qu eme sale en NetBeans 12.5 son que no reconoce los Packages y el tipo de datos String no lo encuentra, asumo que algo no esta haciendo referencia a los archivos necesarios pero no se donde pueda estar la falla...

Comment: ya intentaste instalando la nueva version?

Comment: Hola StringCGE, estás en linux o en windows?.